# how to remove the first 2 key-pairs in hasmap

Tags: java, hashmap, java.util.scanner

I asks the user to put 2 key pairs

```
for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        System.out.print("Enter student ID " + (j + 1) + ": ");
        id = sc.next();
        System.out.print("Enter student name " + (j + 1) + ": ");
        name = sc.next();
        studentList.put(id, name);
    }
```

then I removed the last pair the user entered

```
studentList.remove(id);
```

I ask for another pair and added it into the hashmap

```
System.out.println("Enter username: ");
    username = sc.next();
    System.out.println("Enter password: ");
    password = sc.next();
    studentList.put(username, password);
```

now, I want to ask the user again for another 3 pair

```
for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
        System.out.print("Enter username " + (y + 1) + ": ");
        username = sc.next();
        System.out.print("Enter password " + (y + 1) + ": ");
        password = sc.next();
        studentList.put(username, password);
    }
```

but now, I want to remove the first 2 the user put.

EDIT: I did it by putting the first 2 key pairs in an Array List so that it can be accessed in order.

Comment: requested logic doesn't applied to hashmap structure

Comment: You would probably want a `LinkedHashMap` or similar: `HashMap` is inherently unordered, and thus the values you put it may not come out in the same order.

Comment: You may keep the first two IDs two variables so that you can remove those entries by ID when you want (variations of the idea are thinkable).

Comment: but I want to remove specifically the first 2 ID of my hashmap

Comment: There is no "first two": If you add keys `63` and `64` to a hashmap, then add `65`, you might be surprised that the order of your hashmap could be `64, 65, 63`. It is _unordered_, there is no notion of "first two" that's consistent with insertion order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use interfaces SortedMap or NavigableMap for deleting first two key-pairs,
but you can NOT do it with HashMap, because it doesn't save order. As a hashmap has no order it makes no sense to delete the first entry.